# Wrap an enum in Selene to be accessible in Lua

Tags: c++, enums, lua

I'm using [Selene](https://github.com/jeremyong/Selene) to wrap C++ classes and functions to be accessible from Lua. I have a simple enum class:

```
enum class Motion {
    UP = 0,
    DOWN = 1,
    REPEAT = 2,
};
```

I want to wrap this inside a Lua state so that I can say something like "Motion.DOWN" in Lua and get 1.

First attempt:

```
void register(sel::State &L) {
    L["Motion"].SetClass<Motion>();
}
```

The compiler complains that it's not a class.

```
...
/source/desktop/../external/Selene/include/selene/Class.h:41:10: 
    error: creating pointer to member of non-class type 'Motion'
 void _register_member(lua_State *state,
...
```

Second attempt:

```
void register(sel::State &L) {
    L["Motion"] = Motion;
}
```

This doesn't compile, get errors about "expecting primary expression", it's not valid C++. I get the same errors if I try to use `&Motion`.

Is there a way to do this? Preferably one that doesn't involve me listing out all the enum constants again.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in Selene.

The solution I adopted is to define a class `DynEnum` that internally uses a map to keep track of labels and values.

```
/**
 * Simple class for enum values
 */
class DynEnum {
  public:
    DynEnum(std::map<std::string, int> tbl) : tbl(tbl) {}

    int of(std::string tag) {
        if (tbl.count(tag) > 0) {
            return tbl[tag];
        }
        throw std::runtime_error("Enum tag not found");
    }

    std::string lookup(int v) {
        for (auto &p : tbl) {
            if (p.second == v) {
                return p.first;
            }
        }
        throw std::runtime_error("Enum value not found");
    }

  private:
    std::map<std::string, int> tbl;
};
```

Then instantiate objects like this:

```
DynEnum Motion({
    {"UP", 0},
    {"DOWN", 1},
    {"REPEAT", 2},
});
```

Then bind using Selene:

```
L["Motion"].SetObj(Motion,
    "of", &DynEnum::of,
    "lookup", &DynEnum::lookup);
```

This method has performance overhead but in my application it's not a big deal. It also has the advantage of allowing conversion from number to string in Lua which helps debugging.